# Formatting issue when reading info into an array

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, tostring

i am currently using inheritance and as you can see below, i have two classes, the person and the passenger. In the person i have the main toString() method and in the passenger i call a super.toString() and add the new info, priority booking/noOfBags and the ID. The problem i have is, when the user adds a new passenger to the array, when you print the array the data isn't in the same format as entered. I am pretty sure that i have called everything correctly and im not 100% sure why just the name aspect of the toString messes up (notice that the DOB/ID/noOfBags and priority booking all formatted correctly). If anyone can point me as to why just the name is printing incorrectly it would be greatly appreciated.

**Code**
This is the constructor in the main class Person

```
public Person()
{
    name = new Name();
    dateOfBirth = new Date();

}

public Person(String titleIn, String firstNameIn, String surNameIn, int day, int month, int year)
{
    name = new Name(titleIn, firstNameIn, surNameIn);
    dateOfBirth = new Date(day, month, year);

}
```

Here is the method i use to get the Name and DOB details of the new passenger

```
public void read()
{
    try
    {
        Scanner kbInt = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner kbString = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("***Passenger Details: ***");
        System.out.print("Title : ");titleRead=kbInt.nextLine();
        System.out.print("First Name : ");FNameRead=kbString.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Surname : ");SNameRead=kbString.nextLine();
        name = new Name(titleRead, FNameRead, SNameRead);

        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("***Date of Birth: ***");
        System.out.print("Day : ");dayRead=kbInt.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Month : ");monthRead=kbInt.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Year : ");yearRead=kbString.nextInt();
        dateOfBirth = new Date(dayRead, monthRead, yearRead);   
    }

        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.print("Incorrect input, please input data in the correct format!");
        }
}
```

And finally for the person class, here is the toString

```
public String toString()
{
    String nameAndAge = "Name = " + name + ", DOB = " + dateOfBirth;
    return nameAndAge;
}
```

In the passenger class which inherits from Person, here is the arraylist being made and the constructor

```
private ArrayList<Passenger> passengers = new ArrayList<Passenger>();

//Constructor
public Passenger()
{
    noOfBags = 0;
    priorityBoarding = false;
    id = nextid++;
}

//Initiliaze constructor
public Passenger(String titleIn, String firstNameIn, String surnameIn, int day, int month, int year, int bag, boolean pb)
{
    super(titleIn, firstNameIn, surnameIn, day, month, year);
    noOfBags = bag;
    priorityBoarding = pb;
}
```

Here i add the reading of the noOfBags and priority boarding and add it to the read method in person

```
public void bagsPriorityRead()
{
    Scanner kbInt = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner kbString = new Scanner(System.in);

    super.read();
    System.out.print("Number of bags : ");bagsRead=kbString.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Priority boarding (Y/N) : ");priorityRead=kbString.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Finally, here is the toString method in passenger

```
//ToString Method
public String toString()
{
    return " ID: " +id + " - " + super.toString() + " \tNo of Bags: " +bagsRead + "\tDo they have priority boarding? : " +priorityRead;
}
```

//Added images of the adding in action and the way it is improperly formatted when printing

[image: adding the passenger]

//Improper formatting when printing
[image: Improperly formatted]

As stated above, if anyone could point to where im going wrong/how to fix my error it would be greatly appreciated. If any more code may be needed to find the source of the problem just let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Comment: Is the error you're asking about: `Title: Doe Firstname Mr Surname John` being out of order? Why are you assigning `name = new Name(titleRead, FNameRead, SNameRead);` and such, instead of calling  your Passenger constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem, if anywhere, would be in Name::toString() or that the order of the parameters are wrong in `new Name(x, y, z)`

```
String nameAndAge = "Name = " + name + ", DOB = " + dateOfBirth;
```

But you haven't posted the Name class.

Comment: Apologies, stupidly this is the error, my name class which i didn't even think about was in the wrong order, thanks for bringing it to my attention.